# Taking a screen shot of lock screen in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is there anyway I can take a screen shot of the lock screen on WP8 or if possible on WP7 too?

Comment: is this supposed to be an application or are you asking about how to do it in general (as a user)?

Comment: I should certainly hope not otherwise the next thing you know apps will be taking screenshots of you're unlock code, wont they...

Answer (score 1):

You can't take screenshots of the lock screen progammatically. You can however do this yourself on the device or on the emulator pretty easily.

On the device (WP8 only) press the power and start buttons at the same time. This should take a screenshot and save to a folder in your photos hub. See [Taking a screenshot](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-nz/how-to/wp8/photos/take-a-screenshot).

If you want to take a screenshot on the emulator of the lockscreen you'll need to hit F12 twice to lock the emulator. You can then use the screenshot tools as per normal to take the screenshot. See [How to lock the screen in Windows Phone emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662945%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).